# Can I avoid duplicate css when importing a less file that uses mixins?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3, mixins

I'm attempting to use the less mixins that come with Bootstrap 3 to create more symantic code.

Here's my setup. I have a file called `base.less` that looks something like this:

```
@import "../less/bootstrap.less";

@grid-columns:              12;
@grid-gutter-width:         30px;
@grid-float-breakpoint:     768px;

.wrapper {
  .make-row();
}
.content-main {
  .make-lg-column(8);
}
.content-secondary {
  .make-lg-column(3);
  .make-lg-column-offset(1);
}
```

Then I have a file called `article.less` that has styles that are aonly needed on some of my pages so I only want to include that css if I have to.

```
@import "base.less";

.test-class{
    color: blue;
}

.article-wrapper {
  .make-row();
}
.article-main {
  .make-md-column(6);
}
.article-box {
  .make-lg-column(8);
  .make-lg-column-offset(1);
}
```

What is happening is that a lot of redundent styles are being created in the `article.css` file that are also in the `base.css` file. I was hoping that by importing the `base.less` file that it would skip creating any redudnt styles.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Less 1.5 introduces Reference Imports](http://lesscss.org/#changes):

> We have another import option - reference. This means that any
>   variables or mixins or selectors will be imported, but never output.
>
> e.g. if you have
>
> ```css
> .a {
>     color: green;
> }
> ```
>
> in a file and import it
>
> `@import (reference) "file.less";` then that file will not be output,
>   but you could do
>
> ```css
> .b {
>     .a;
> }
> ```
>
> and `color: green;` would be output inside the `.b` selector only.
>   This also works with extends, so you can use extends to bring complex
>   selector groups from a less or css file into your main file. One
>   use-case might be to grab a set of selectors from bootstrap without
>   including the whole library.

This seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: And just to be clear, my solution was to replace `@import "base.less";
` with `@import (reference) "base.less";`

Comment: awesome, this is a great tip!